# Recursive systematic convolutional code (RSC) realization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, convolution, algorithms, channelcoding

How can I implement $\rm RSC(2,1,2)$ in MATLAB? Can I use `convenc` function to build RSC?

The `convenc` function has 2 arguments: `code = convenc(msg,trellis)` where `trellis=poly2trellis(ConstraintLength,CodeGenerator)`, and the generator polynomial for this RSC is:
$$
G=\left(1,\frac{1+D^{2}}{1+D+D^{3}}\right)\quad\text{or}\quad G=\left(1,\frac{5}{7}\right)
$$
but for `poly2trellis` argument `CodeGenerator` need to be in octal.

[image]

Comment: Why not implement the state machine directly? It's pretty easy. Hint: you need a `current_state` vector and a `next_state` vector.

Comment: @MBaz If I use _convenc_ function, then for decoder  I can use _vitdec_. This is a part/block of communication system, which need to be tested in MatLab.

Comment: Well, your first question is how to implement this system in Matlab. It seems like your question is more specific -- maybe edit your question to clarify what you need?

Comment: try this: t = poly2trellis( 3, [7 5], 7);
code=convenc(input, t);

Comment: You can use: poly2trellis(4,[15,5],15) 1+D+D^3 is equivalent with [1 1 0 1]

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered but let me structure it for future readers.
From the MATLAB help for the function `poly2trellis`, here is how you can do it:

`TRELLIS = poly2trellis(CONSTRAINTLENGTH, CODEGENERATOR, FEEDBACKCONNECTION)`

Hence for the figure in the question:
 `RSC_trellis = poly2trellis( 3, [7 5], 7);`

Or, for the other possible RSC encoder, i.e. choosing the lower branch to be fedback:
 `RSC_trellis = poly2trellis( 3, [7 5], 5);`